# What's the equivalent of NSArray's writeToFile: atomically: in Swift and Array?

Tags: cocoa, swift

I've been learning about Swift and building an Cocoa app which is based on Swift, and faced the issue that Swift's built-in `Array` type doesn't have `writeToFile: atomically:` method which is implemented in Objective-C's `NSArray`.

So how can I write the contents of the array to a file? Is there any such method in Swift? (FYI, I wasn't able to find the documentation of the Swift's Array type much like [the Objective-C's NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html). If you did, please link it in comment section.)

Or if it cannot be done to write the content of an array to the file in Swift using the built-in `Array`, what's the best alternative? I think `NSArray` is also available in Swift code, but I rather want to avoid Objective-C's classes. Or should I use extension to implement the feature in `Array`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure if the "native" ability for writing arrays to files exists in Swift, but since arrays can be bridged to `NSArray`s, you should be able to write your arrays to a file like this:

```
let mySwiftArray = ... // Your Swift array
let cocoaArray : NSArray = mySwiftArray
cocoaArray.writeToFile(filePath, atomically:true);
```

The second line creates a "Bridged" object of type `NSArray`, which should give you access to all methods from the foundation.

Answer (score 1):

This will work...

```
let array = ["One", "Two", "Three"] as NSArray
array.writeToFile("/Users/xxx/Desktop/trial.txt", atomically:true)
```

Output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>One</string>
    <string>Two</string>
    <string>Three</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

But you must cast it as an NSArray

```
let array = ["One", "Two", "Three"]  // Native Swift array will not work
array.writeToFile("/Users/xxx/Desktop/trial.txt", atomically:true)
```

will *not* work.