# How to call Objective-C's NSArray class method from within Swift?

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I want to use `NSArray`'s `arrayWithContentsOfFile` method in Swift since I have to create an Swift Array from the contents of a file, but how can I call it from within Swift code?

Since `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` is a class method implemented in Objective-C's built-in `NSArray` type, I cannot call it as called in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246749/whats-the-equivalent-of-nsarrays-writetofile-atomically-in-swift-and-array), which calls an instance method by type-casting the Swift's `Array` to Objective-C's `NSArray`.

So is there any way to call the method, or any equivalent method like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method can be called in Swift like so:
`NSArray(contentsOfFile: "PATH")`

Using the method like so: `NSArray.arrayWithContentsOfFile("PATH")` is deprecated.

This is a constructor, and should be used in the following manner:

```
var array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: "PATH")
```

Comment: Technically, there are two different methods called here. `NSArray(contentsOfFile: "PATH")` calls `-initWithContentsOfFile:` in Objective-C, whereas `NSArray.arrayWithContentsOfFile("PATH")` (note: not `withContentsOfFile`) calls `+arrayWithContentsOfFile:`. It is true that the initializer is preferred over the class method when an initializer is available.

Comment: @newacct Yes; however, `NSArray.arrayWithContentsOfFile("PATH")` is deprecated and therefore should not be used, as I stated in my answer.

Comment: It's not just deprecated, it's unavailable in Swift. The compiler maps the ObjC initializer to a Swift initializer, then disables the ObjC convenience constructor because it's known to just call through to the similarly named initializer.