# Fill an array with strings from a txt file [Solution from XCode6 Beta1 no longer works]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode6

A few weeks ago, I asked how to [Fill an array with strings from a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327517/fill-an-array-with-strings-from-a-txt-file/24327694?noredirect=1#comment37605876_24327694).

A few answers (that worked) had been given, but since I updated Xcode 6 to Beta 3, they don't work anymore.

The code is this one:

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource("data", ofType: "txt")
let dico = NSString(contentsOfFile: path).componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Since Beta 3, the following error is being displayed about `NSString`:

```
'init(contentsOfFile:)' is unavailable: APIs deprecated of iOS7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation, you'll see that, as the error says, `+stringWithContentsOfFile:` is deprecated.  The reason is that there is no error indication and it doesn't specify which encoding to use.

You could change the third line to something like

```
var error = NSError?
let dico = NSString(contentsOfFile:path, usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error:&error)
```

Noting that `dico` might be `nil`, in which case you should inspect `error` to see what went wrong.

(Also, in an ideal world, you should use the URL-based APIs in preference to the path-based ones.  The path APIs aren't deprecated *yet*, but I suspect in the long run they will be.)