# How can I store an array in a separate file?

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I'am planing to use a couple of large arrays in my project and like to store the arrays in a separate file. is this possible?
here is my main viewcontroller example with the array **"gruppe"** I like to have in a separate file:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var gruppe = ["new york", "sydney", "paris"]
@IBAction func knopf(sender: UIButton) {
println(gruppe[0])
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
// File 1
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func knopf(sender: UIButton) {
        println(DataClass.gruppe()[0])
    }
}

// File 2
class DataClass {
    class func gruppe() -> [String] {
        return ["new york", "sydney", "paris"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can bridge a Swift array to a NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246749/whats-the-equivalent-of-nsarrays-writetofile-atomically-in-swift-and-array).

doing something like:

```
let cocoaArray : NSArray = gruppe
cocoaArray.writeToFile("pathToYourFile", atomically:true)
```

Comment: Sorry, not an external File, only in a second SWIFT file.

Comment: your question is confusing then.  Do you want to make a *duplicate* array within Swift?

Comment: I'm assuming he just wants to decouple the data from the logic. Perfectly sensible.